# PySpark flatMap to Flatten List in a List

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, flatmap

Is there a way to use `flatMap` to flatten a list in an rdd like so:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([[1,2,3],[6,7,8]])

rdd.flatMap(lambda r: [[r[0],r[1],r[2],[r[2]+1,r[2]+2]]]).collect()
```

My desired output:

```
[[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]]
```

The actual output:

```
[[1,2,3,[4,5]], [6,7,8,[9,10]]]
```

I understand `flatMap` flattens the array appropriately, and I am not confused as to the actual output above, but I would like to know if there is a way to effectively flatten the inner list.

Answer (score 2):

Please modify your code like below to get the desired output

```
rdd.flatMap(lambda r: [[r[0],r[1],r[2],r[2]+1,r[2]+2]]).collect()
```

Comment: The point is that I can't modify it that way. I have a structure as above, and I'd like to flatten it without calling a list comprehension.

Comment: If the given answer is not what your expected, can you please edit and improve your question? It is quite unclear what you intend to do

Comment: I'd like to flatten the list as it is posed in the question. Given a list that looks like `[1,2,3,[4,5]]`, I'd like to flatten it to `[1,2,3,4,5]` with the tools available in pyspark.

Comment: @WaterCrane does this answers your question ?

Comment: @eliasah No. The question is not about reformatting the expression, but rather creating a solution to flatten non homogeneous objects.